# Add data to Jquery.Ajax post when uploading file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

I'm building a drag n drop upload feature for my MVC 4 webapp using this tutorial:
http://hayageek.com/drag-and-drop-file-upload-jquery/

However, besides the file, I also want to send info regarding where it came from (some ID for instance) and the type (domain-type).

In my ajax post below, how can I add extra data and read it server side? 
In the tutorial code a line with 'extra data' is seen, however it is not actually implemented.

```
function sendFileToServer(formData, status) {
    var uploadURL = '/home/upload';
    var extraData = {}; //Extra Data.
    var jqXHR = $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhrobj.upload) {
                xhrobj.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                    var percent = 0;
                    var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                    var total = event.total;
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                    }
                    //Set progress
                    status.setProgress(percent);
                }, false);
            }
            return xhrobj;
        },
        url: uploadURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            status.setProgress(100);

            //$("#status1").append("File upload Done<br>");
        }
    });

    status.setAbort(jqXHR);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the data with formData?

Comment: yes, but server side I do HttpPostedFileBase myFile = Request.Files["file"] to read the fill, which ends up as NULL when I add some data to the 'data' property in the call.

Answer (score 1):

To pass additional data to your controller via Ajax Upload File, it just needs to append your additional data to formData in your Ajax call function(sendFileToServer). i.e. you'd like to pass an upload target folder:

```
formData.append('targetFolder', 'User File Upload Folder');
```

and in your action get access to your additional parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string targetFolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating a workaround, I'm passing the extra data (id etc) via the URL which I receive as parameters on the controller method.